# Proof of Rao Blackwellization

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics, rao-blackwell

I am reading this [classic paper (Information and the Accuracy Attainable in the Estimation of Statistical Parameters)](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-0919-5_16) by CR Rao where he introduces the idea of minimizing the variance of an unbiased estimate using sufficient statistics. I have some difficulty in following his 2-line-proof - specifically Equations (3.7-3.8).

I will reproduce his proof here.

Say $T$ is the sufficient statistic, then the probability distribution $\phi(x ; \theta)$ can be written as $$
\phi(x ; \theta)=\Phi(T, \theta) \psi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right)
$$
where $\psi$ is independent of $\theta$.

If $t$ is an unbiased estimate, then $$
\theta=\int t \phi \pi d x_{i}=\int f(T) \Phi(T, \theta) d T
$$
where $f(T)$ is a function independent of $\theta$

> Shouldn't there be a Jacobian term due to change of variables from $x_i$
>   to $T$?

Further, $$
\begin{aligned} \int\left(t-\theta^{2}\right) \phi \pi d x_{i} &=\int[t-f(T)]^{2} \phi \pi d x_{i}+\int[f(T)-\theta]^{2} \Phi(T, \theta) d T \\ & \geq \int[f(T)-\theta]^{2} \Phi(T, \theta) d T \end{aligned}
$$

> How does the first equality follow?

Thanks in advance,

P.S.: I am familiar with the other ways of proving the Rao-Blackwellization theorem using variance decomposition lemma. I specifically want to understand the author's approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument is that, if there exists an estimator $\delta(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=\delta(\mathbf X)$ of $\theta$ then
\begin{align}\theta&=\Bbb E_\theta[\delta(\mathbf X)]\\
&=\Bbb E_\theta\{\underbrace{\Bbb E_\theta[\delta(\mathbf X)\mid T]}_{\text{call this }f(T)}\}\\
&=\Bbb E_\theta[f(T)]\\
&=\int f(t) \Phi(t;\theta)\text{d}t\end{align}
assuming $\Phi(t;\theta)$ is the density of $T$

The second argument is Pythagore's theorem, namely that
\begin{align}
\text{var}(\delta) &=\int\overbrace{\left(\delta(\mathbf x)-\theta\right)^{2}}^{\text{square outside}} \phi(\mathbf x;\theta) \text{d}\mathbf x\\
&=\mathbb E_\theta[(\delta(\mathbf X)-\mathbb E[\delta(\mathbf X)|T(\mathbf X)]+\mathbb E[\delta(\mathbf X)|T(\mathbf X)]-\theta)^2]\\
&=\mathbb E_\theta[(\delta(\mathbf X)-\underbrace{\mathbb E[\delta(\mathbf X)|T(\mathbf X)]}_{\text{this is }f(T)})^2]+0+\mathbb E_\theta[(\underbrace{\mathbb E[\delta(\mathbf X)|T(\mathbf X)]}_{\text{this is }f(T)}-\theta)^2]\qquad\text{[Pythagore]}\\
&=\int[\delta(\mathbf x)-f(T(\mathbf x))]^{2} \phi(\mathbf x;\theta) \text{d}\mathbf x+\int[f(t)-\theta]^{2} \Phi(t, \theta) \text{d}t
\end{align}